# How do I include a root CA certifciate in my node JS server?

Tags: node.js, npm, module, ssl-certificate

I'm using npm v 5.7.1 on Mac High Sierra.  I just installed this module

```
npm install ssl-root-cas
```

(for some reason, adding "-g" didn't work).  Then i have this in my JS file

```
require('ssl-root-cas')
    .inject()
    .addFile(fs.readFileSync(conf.root_cert));
```

However, upon executing the above code (specifically the "inject()" line), I get the error

```
/Users/satishp/Documents/workspace/projA/node_modules/ssl-root-cas/ssl-root-cas.js:3637
  var filepaths = filepath.split(/\//g);
                           ^

TypeError: filepath.split is not a function
    at Array.module.exports.rootCas.addFile (/Users/satishp/Documents/workspace/projA/node_modules/ssl-root-cas/ssl-root-cas.js:3637:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/satishp/Documents/workspace/projA/server.js:79:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:662:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:673:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:575:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:515:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:507:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:703:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:660:3
```

I'm somewhat confused about how to proceed.  How do I overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the file path for the `addFile` function, no need to manually load the file content:

```
require('ssl-root-cas')
  .inject()
  .addFile(conf.root_cert);
```